# SQL Server 2012 Enterprise: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a query that finds the Brand ID, Brand Name, Brand Type and average price of products for the brand that has the largest average product price.  Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT  LGBrand.Brand_ID, Brand_Name, Brand_Type, MAX(AVG(Prod_Price))
AS      AvgPrice
FROM    LGProduct, LGBrand
GROUP BY    LGBrand.Brand_ID, Brand_Name, Brand_Type
ORDER BY AvgPrice DESC
```

I'm very new to SQL.  Before I had the same code without the "MAX" command, but it brought back the average for all the brands in the output.

Not really sure where to go.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?  You can't have a MAX(AVG(price)) if you use the same group by, if the average is 5, the the min and max are also 5.  Are you trying to get the average price AND the max price?  Or do you want the average price by brand, and then the max result from the average brands?.  Please elaborate on expected results.

Comment: Also, why are you cross-joining LGProduct and LGBrand?  I am pretty sure you want a real join there.  Also, don't use that ancient comma(",") syntax in your FROM clause, it just leads to accidental cross-joins. Use the explicit `FROM..JOIN..` syntax instead.

Comment: The expected results should be one row of information from the tables, staying the Brand Name that has the highest average price of products.

Answer (score 0):

Won't TOP 1 give you what you want?

```
SELECT  TOP 1 LGBrand.Brand_ID, Brand_Name, Brand_Type, AVG(Prod_Price) AS Avg_Prod_Price
FROM    LGProduct, LGBrand
GROUP BY    LGBrand.Brand_ID, Brand_Name, Brand_Type
ORDER BY Avg_Prod_Price DESC
```

Comment: That actually gives a better answer than I got, but according to the book (this is a homework assignment) it's not the right answer.  I'm going to fiddle with it to see if I can get it to give the correct answer.